# Removing everything after first word JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The title is a little bland but my problem is explained below.

At the moment I currently have a live search:

[image: image1]

This does what I want it to do, but of course, that's only possible with a little bit of JS.

Now when you click one of the options it gives you from your search it'd usually take you to a link, but I added the below JS so that it removes all HTML code from it and it appends the selected username from the drop down into a text box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#livesearch").click(function(){
            var value = $(this).html();
            var input = $('#append_value');
            var content = value;
            var text = $(content).text(); //removes all HTML
            input.val(text);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now, this is all perfect and everything but there's a problem. When you select one option from the drop down it appends both options to the text box:

[image: image2]

Now, this may have something to do with the code above, but I just want whichever option the user has selected to be appended to the text box.

So, for example, I search for the battlefield and I get a result of `battlefield1` and `battlefield2`. If the user selected `battlefield2` I want `battlefield2` to be placed in the textbox, and vice versa.

I've been trying to do this since 1pm EST so you can trust me when I say I've looked plenty of times for a solution.

Thank you in advance for your help. :)

**Edit:**

What I'm doing the search with (yes I realize SQL is deprecated):

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function lightbg_clr() {
        $('#qu').val("");
        $('#textbox-clr').text("");
        $('#search-layer').css({"width":"auto","height":"auto"});
        $('#livesearch').css({"display":"none"});
        $("#qu").focus();
    };

    function fx(str) {
        var s1=document.getElementById("qu").value;
        var xmlhttps;
        if (str.length==0) {
            document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
            document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
            document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display="block";
            $('#textbox-clr').text("");
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttps=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttps=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTPS");
        }
        xmlhttps.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttps.readyState==4 && xmlhttps.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttps.responseText;
                document.getElementById("livesearch").style.display="block";
                $('#textbox-clr').text("X");
            }
        }
        xmlhttps.open("GET","scripts/search_friends.php?n="+s1,true);
        xmlhttps.send();
    }
</script>
<input type="text" onKeyUp="fx(this.value)" autocomplete="off" name="qu" id="qu" class="form-control" placeholder="Name of the person or group">
<div class="list-group" id="livesearch"></div>
<input type="text" id="append_valueq">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#livesearch").click(function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            var input = $('#append_valueq');
            var content = value;
            var text = $(content).text();
            input.val(text);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**search_friends.php**

```
<?php
include('../Connections/ls.php'); //script to connect to DB
$s1=$_REQUEST["n"];
$select_query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username LIKE '%".$s1."%'";
$sql=mysql_query($select_query) or die (mysql_error());
$s="";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $s=$s."
    <a href='javascript:void(0)'>".$row['Username']."</a>
    "   ;
}
echo $s;
?>
```

This ultimately gives me the result you see in the first image.

I'm realizing now that the problem I'm having is the fact that div has an id of livesearch (`<div class="list-group" id="livesearch"></div>`), so it's selecting the whole div instead of the actual options in the dropdown...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant HTML. What is the value of the `value` variable? (As an aside, `var content = value;` is pointless, it just results in two variables with the same value.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Because of this comment I realized I am doing something wrong with the way I'm trying to append to the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.val()` instead of `html()` while fetching the value.

Comment: When I try that nothing happens. Thank you for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a really simple way to do this.

Since you haven't provided your HTML code, I'll show what I would have done.

You can get the value of the click with:

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").value();
```

Make sure you don't include the hashtag/pound sign in the id.

Then, you can apply this value, let's say you call it val, this way:
    document.getElementById("textbox").value = val

I've created a JSFiddle that kind-of shows the concept. See if you can get it to work with your own code: https://jsfiddle.net/1j4m1ekc/7/

If the problem persists, just let me know. I'd also like to see your html.

Comment: `.value` is a property, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't need a solution right away for this as I've found another alternative to do what I want to do, but it would be greatly appreciated in case someone else from the Stackoverflow community has a question similar to this and need a solution. The solution I found is below.

This is still considered a live search but, I created a scrollable container and listed all of the users in that container, so it now looks like this.

[image: image1]

Now from that container I found a script online that will filter out any and all users that do not match the input from the search box. The script I found is from here: [Live Search](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/) and if you want to take a look at a demo as to how the script works, [View Demo](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery/demo/jquery_demo_live_comment_search.htm). So now when I enter a search term into the text box it looks like this

[image]

This may not be the greatest solution but it works for me and does what I want it to do. Maybe it'll work for you as well :)